# Replace all spaces except the first & last ones

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

I want to replace all whitespaces except the first and the last one as this image.

How to replace only the red ones?

[how to replace the red space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSQ13.png)

I tried :

```
.replace(/\s/g, "_");
```

but it captures all spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest match and capture the initial/trailing whitespaces that will be kept and then matching any other whitespace that will be replaced with `_`:

```js
var s = " One Two There ";
console.log(
 s.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)|\s/g, function($0,$1) {
     return $1 ? $1 : '_';
   })
);
```

Here,

- `(^\s+|\s+$)` - Group 1: either *one or more* whitespaces at the start or end of the string
- `|` - or
- `\s` - any other whitespace.

The `$0` in the callback method represents the whole match, and `$1` is the argument holding the contents of Group 1. Once `$1` matches, we return its contents, else, replace with `_`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^` to check for first character and `$` for last, in other words, search for space that is either preceded by something other than start of line, or followed by something thing other than end of line:

```js
var rgx = /(?!^)(\s)(?!$)/g;
// (?!^) => not start of line
// (?!$) => not end of line
console.log(' One Two Three '.replace(rgx, "_"));
```

Comment: FYI: If there are more than 1 whitespaces at the start or end, this will not work as expected.